# How to get the total size of files in a Directory in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to copy some files into a directory  using Ruby, i need to assure the  files inside  the directory not exceed 2GB. is there any way to check the total size of files inside the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows, You can use win32ole gem to calculate the same

```
 require 'win32ole'

 fso = WIN32OLE.new('Scripting.FileSystemObject')

 folder = fso.GetFolder('directory path')

  p folder.name

  p folder.size

 p folder.path
```

Comment: Obviously, only on a Windows system.

Answer (score 9):

Just `mydir`:

```
Dir['mydir/*'].select { |f| File.file?(f) }.sum { |f| File.size(f) }
```

`mydir` and all subdirectories:

```
Dir['mydir/**/*'].select { |f| File.file?(f) }.sum { |f| File.size(f) }
```

However, it's the sum of exact file sizes, not the space they occupy on the disk. For disk usage, this is more accurate:

```
Dir['mydir/*'].select { |f| File.file?(f) }
.sum { |f| File.stat(f).then { |s| s.blocks * s.blksize } }
```

Comment: The last one is not really correct: Most file systems today use a block size of 4096 and even if you find out the correct block size for your current dir up front, other filesystems could still be mounted somewhere in the tree, giving wildly wrong results then. I think adding the sizes is more useful.

Comment: @FelixDombek Good point. Let me rewrite that; this should be exact.

Comment: Thanks ... one more remark: it could be useful to use `lstat` over `stat` so that symlinked files aren't counted multiple times. (Maybe depending on usecase, though).

Comment: Perhaps use other [File::Stat](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/File/Stat.html) methods: `Dir['mydir/*'].sum { |f| File.stat(f).then { |s| s.file? && !s.directory? && !s.symlink? ? s.blocks * s.blksize : 0 } }`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland As Felix Dombek says in their comment about `lstat`, it depends on the use case. A directory is a file that takes up space, so if you are checking for disk usage it should be counted. If you try to copy a symbolic link you will copy the file instead (unless `cp -P`), so counting the file size of the link's target makes sense in OP's scenario (while it wouldn't in some others).

Comment: This will give the logical size and not handle symbolic links, hard links and sparse files.  The OP needs to give more context what he want to know.

Answer (score 3):

For Unix-flavoured OS's, it may be easiest to simply shell out to the operating system to use the [du](http://www.linfo.org/du.html) command.

For example

```
du -bs #=> 1214674782
```

is the disk space in bytes consumed by my computer's current directory and its nested subdirectories.

```
du ../.rvm/src -bs #=> 722526755
```

is the same for a specified directory. Within Ruby, you can use the [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Kernel.html#method-i-system) command:

```
s = system("du -bs") #=> 1214674782
```

To obtain the bytes consumed by the current directory only (and not nested subdirectories) remove `"b"` from the flags.

```
s = system("du -s") #=> 1301136
```

Note disk space consumption is somewhat more than the total of all file sizes, but that could be a better measure of what you are looking for.